# VBA how to rename all buttons in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, rename

I'm trying to execute a very simple procedure in which I would like all the buttons (copied from a worksheet to another) to be renamed as "Button " & number.

Somehow all the buttons (which are non-active-x) except the first 2 are renamed.

The code I wrote is:

```
Dim button As button
i = 1
For Each button In ws.Buttons
    button.Name = "Button " & i
    i = i + 1
Next button
```

Comment: If you are sure the two buttons do actually belong to `ws.Buttons`, then try a) accessing `Buttons` by index, not with `for each`, and b) copying all references to Buttons to an array and then looping through the array changing names.

Comment: Ok, addressing Buttons by index worked. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I'm posting my comment as an answer now to allow this question to be marked as solved. Please check the accept tick at some point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a collection while enumerating it is a bad idea more often than not. It would appear the name changes also affect the `for each` enumerator, so some buttons get skipped.

Try either of the following:

- Accessing `Buttons` by index, not with `For Each`.
- Copying all references to Buttons to an array (i.e. take a snapshot of the collection) and then looping through the array changing names.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to rename all the (NON-active x) buttons on my active worksheet. I would LOVE to access them by index, because as buttons are added, removed, changed, etc., I may have Code names "Button 3" and "Button 6" and no others. Consequently, accessing them by Code name is unreliable. Any solid info on how to change button captions via index would be soo helpful. Thanks so much!